# Google Sheet Notes will not scroll for person with "Viewer" only permission

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, scrollable

When I give a person "Viewer" access to a Google sheet with notes in cells, they cannot access the entire cell note.  When they open the note, the note comes up already scrolled to the bottom of the note and **the user cannot scroll the note** to see what is at the top.  The note is frozen at the bottom of the note.  So the viewer cannot see the full note which makes it useless for them.  BTW this problem is occurring while accessing the spreadsheet within the Google Sheets APP on an iPad or iPhone.

I was expecting that a "viewer only" of the spreadsheet would be able to scroll the whole note and be able to read its complete content even though as a "viewer only" they would not be able to edit any of the content.  The only work around is to download the spreadsheet as an excel file which allows the viewer to read the complete content of all of the notes. That is not a very acceptable way to do things.  BTW this problem is occurring while accessing the spreadsheet within the Google Sheets APP on an iPad or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. The sheet is shared among many users.

For us, the solution was trivial. Probably someone set the View/Freez rows to 10. When it was set to 4 (which was the value we needed), the problem vanished.